# Regular expression to match SQL query regions

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to split the SQL regions by **region** and its **value**.

Considering the SQL query format is the sequential values from the below array:

```cs
string[] regions = new string[] { "SELECT", "FROM", "WHERE", "GROUP BY", "HAVING", "ORDER BY", "OFFSET", "LIMIT" };
```

Basic Example:

> SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE column2 = 1 ORDER BY column3 LIMIT 10

Result:

```
SELECT -> column1
FROM -> table1
WHERE -> column2 = 1
ORDER BY -> column3
LIMIT -> 10
```

Another example with subquery example:

> SELECT id FROM (SELECT id2 FROM table LIMIT 2) WHERE x = 1 OFFSET 5 LIMIT 10

```
SELECT -> id
FROM -> (SELECT id2 FROM table LIMIT 2)
WHERE -> x = 1
OFFSET -> 5
LIMIT -> 10
```

With this result, I want to save it in a dictionary with key (region) and value (the value from that region). From above example, I want a regex capable to match against that FROM region, and split the key and value again.

With the following regex, I can retrieve the value from a keyword only if its in parenthesis. However, I cannot retrieve what keyword (region) is from.

```cs
Regex rx = new Regex(@"\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))\)");
var matches = rx.Matches("SELECT (id) FROM (SELECT (id2) FROM (table)) WHERE (x = 1) LIMIT (10)");
```

[Regex result in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSYEn.png)

Another problem is, for the above query, I don't know that the last result is from LIMIT. According to the regions array above, query format begins with SELECT and ends with LIMIT. Thus, the fourth element has to be a GROUP BY but it's a value for LIMIT.

Comment: Do you have to do this with a regexp? It would be better to look for a SQL parser library.

Comment: A regular expresion won't be able to deal with skipping over subqueries easily.

Comment: I think you refer to "clauses".

Comment: What if your table is named `WHERE` etc? The L in SQL stands for language. Pattern matching using regex can't do it: You need a language parser.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your problem, i believe that you should try and use this:

```
^\s*SELECT\s+([a-zA-Z_,\s]+)\s+FROM\s+([a-zA-Z_]+)\s*$
```

It should solve all your problems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).